# DTLS Implementation on VoIP

Tags: ssl, asterisk, sip, dtls, jitsi

I have a dilemma about my final project.

The idea is to compare the QoS parameters (jitter, throughput, delay, packet loss) and to compare the security aspects ( prevent 3rd party on capturing voice data, firewall testing ) between (a.) Asterisk with TLS and (b.) Asterisk with DTLS.

I have several questions related to my final project:

1. I can't find any source code to enable DTLS security runs over my asterisk server (so far it has been implemented on WebRTC service only). Is it possible to enable it on my Asterisk Server and secure a VoIP call via softphone (Jitsi / Blink)?
2. Should I install separate SIP Server for my DTLS to work on Asterisk IP PBX?
3. Can a TLS-supported softphone (no softphone formally supports DTLS i found so far) runs DTLS?

With all due respects, I'd really be grateful if you reply my message. I'm in a little confusion here and I hope you could help me with a way or more.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding #3, DTLS runs over UDP and TLS runs over TCP, so it's unlikely that a softphone that has support for TLS but does not actually state support for DTLS would actually support it.  You would probably be better off finding a way to use WebRTC for the DTLS side.

Comment: Why softphones use tls instead of dtls? It doesnt make sense to me because in my opinion, voip call via softphone uses udp. cmiiw

Comment: I should have given a more clear answer.  VoIP phones use two protocols: one for signaling (usually SIP) and one for media (usually RTP).  SIP is usually sent over UDP, TCP, or TCP+TLS.  It is defined for SCTP and I think there is a draft spec for DTLS but I have never seen either used.  Media is almost always sent as UDP, since it needs to be real-time.  If you want to look at encrypted media, look into SRTP (RFC 3711).  There is also ZRTP (less common -- RFC 6189), and DTLS-SRTP (RFC 5764), which is the flavor used in WebRTC (main difference is key exchange in SRTP happens in the signaling).